# Different ErrorCount in Windows xp and windows 7

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-7, bde

I am working with Delphi 7,BDE components, and SQL Server.

I have a Customer table with columns *No*, *Name* and *Age*. I am not supposed to update *Name* so in a trigger I have added a check: if the customer name has changed I raise an error.

If I try to update *Name* from within SQL Server my trigger throws this error:

```
Msg ******, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Showerror, Line 1456
Customer Name can not be changed. if you really want to change Please contact associate manager or whoever has authority. Please do not consider if you do not want to change. 
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Now in Delphi if I try to update *Name* in the Customer table my error handling code is below.

Issue: when running under XP the errorCount is 3, under Windows 7 it is 4. ShowMessage() output:

**Windows XP:**

1) *General SQL error.*

2) *Customer Name can not be changed. if you really want to change Please contact associate manager or whoever has

autho.*  <-- **autho** is displaying in a second line here

3) *The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.*

**Windows 7:**

1) *General SQL error.*

2) *Customer Name can not be changed. if you really want to change Please contact associate manager or whoever has.*

3) *authoè¸ö*

4) *The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.*

Code:

```
try
  Post;
except on E:EDBEngineError do
  begin
    // below line is displaying different results.
    ShowMessage('Total Errors: '+IntToStr(E.ErrorCount));
    for i := 0 to E.ErrorCount - 1 do
      with E.Errors[i] do
      begin
        if NativeError = 0 then
        begin
        end
        else 
        begin
          sDatabaseerror := sDatabaseerror + Message + #13#10;
        end;
      end; 

    if sDatabaseerror <> '' then
      MessageDlg('Error is:  ' + #13#10 + sDatabaseerror , mtError, [mbOK], 0);
  end;
end;
```

As a result i am not able to differentiate how to display errors to user.

Comment: If you are not supposed to change the contents of the Name column, the thing to do is to prevent it happening in the first place - you just set the ReadOnly property of the Name field in your dataset to True.

Comment: Don't the BDE - it's obsolete and has been for years, and not the world's most reliable db engine.  Since you're using SqlServer, use TAdoQuery components instead - the'll give you far less trouble than the BDE and its infernal TTable and TQuery.

Comment: @MartynA: it's very Old application i am not suppose to change the way i want.

Comment: Well, if you're stuck with the BDE, you should definitely try marking the Name column read-only in your app, because I doubt whether anyone is likely to investigate the problem your q is asking about.

Comment: Back when our company's software used BDE, we had *major* issues on Windows 7 - specifically with installation/management of BDE on each client machine. Once we switched to ADO all our nightmares went away. One of the issues we had with BDE was it did not want to allow more than one application to connect to the same database. There were sloppy work-arounds though. Also, later versions of Delphi don't even have BDE anymore. It's been deprecated for like 10 years, even before Vista came out. It's a wonder it works at all in Windows 7.

Comment: Besides that, your errors look like a problem with how BDE is parsing and interpreting the response back from the SQL Server. Not much can be done to fix an ancient system like BDE. You'll have to seek alternative ways.